# How can I turn off creating a sub folder for a newly added project in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

When I try to add a new project in a solutin folder by browsing a folder, let's say

**..\MyFolder**

and give a new to my new Project: MyProject

The result seems to be:

**..\MyFolder\MyProject\MyProject.cspoj**

but I want to achieve

**..\MyFolder\MyProject.cspoj**

And Icannot see any option or check-box on new project addin dialog box.

How can I turn of the feature to insert the new project in a auto-created subfolder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Logically  VS creates seperate folder for each project where code resides. It also keeps the project file in same directory for ease of use and portability. You can however manually move the projects file to desired location but have to update solution/references.